# Get value of a cell that next to a specific one in Excel

Tags: excel, text, find, range, rows

I'm trying to make in excel a cell that every time you write something above that cell, it finds the text you typed in a specific column and returns the value of the cell that's next to it. 
Example:

Derp <---I type the word "Derp" here
1246.53 <--this returns the value next to "Derp" that found in the cells below

```
Names     Values
X         173
ZN        5345
Q         76578
Derp      1246.53 <---returns this
AyyLmao   0.5
```

I already tried using Find and Match but they return some other values so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: [vlookup](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function) can do this

Comment: `VLOOKUP` won't work, becuse the list is not sorted in an ascending order.

Comment: @pnuts What's nonsense?

Comment: maybe HLOOKUP will work for you ascending order has nothing to do with Vlookup it will work correctly as long as there are no 2 Derps in column

Comment: @pnuts OK, I see you must add `FALSE` as `Range_lookup` when it's not sorted in an ascending order.

Comment: @Gabriel Soto, you metioned that match and index will not work... it is working... try =INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH("Derp",A2:A6,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these values are in cells `A1:B6`, you can do: `VLOOKUP("Derp", A2:B6, 2, FALSE)`.

A better habit would be to place the item you are lookup up, in this example, `"Derp"` in a different cell, say, `D1`. This would allow you replace the formula with `VLOOKUP(D1, A2:B6, 2, FALSE)` and allow you to type any name/value in `D1`.

Even better, you can make your formula more readable and dynamic by using [`Named Ranges`](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html). That is, name `A2:B6` `lookup_tbl` and name `D1` `item_to_lookup` and you replace the formula with `VLOOKUP(item_to_lookup, lookup_tbl, 2, FALSE)`.

Comment: @GabrielSolo - note the "FALSE" in the formulas above; it ensures VLOOKUP finds an exact match, instead of a best guess (which assumes the data is sorted). When you used INDEX/MATCH, it is likely that you did not set this option.